# sed to search for multiple words and remove those lines

Tags: shell, sed

I have a master file with more than 50000 lines and I need to remove around 20000 lines from actual file, for this I used `grep -vE` command which is showing an error as too many arguments.

I'm using `sed` command to remove those using for loop. But it is taking so much time to remove as 20000 `sed` commands are going to initialize.

```
for i in `cat 20000-words.txt`; do 
    sed -i -e "/$i/ d" 50000-lines.txt
done
```

Comment: Is `20000-words.txt` contains each word a line?

Comment: @Gnouc : Yes it is having one word for one line and it is single word only.

Comment: Please do not cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935727/sed-to-search-for-multiple-words-and-remove-those-lines

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that 20000-words.txt is already in the format of one word per line, do:

```
grep -vFf 20000-words.txt 50000-lines.txt >50000-filtered-lines.txt
```

The `-f` argument to grep tells it to read patterns from a file, one pattern per line, instead of taking them as command line arguments.  The `-F` argument to grep tells it that the patterns should be used as literal strings rather than regular expressions.

Comment: This is ultimately super. It worked in rocket speed.
Thank You so much @godlygeek

Comment: @SriharshaKalluru, awesome - please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of it!

Answer (score 1):

To do it without `grep` and assume that you don't have duplicated lines, you can:

```
$ sort 20000-words.txt 50000-lines.txt | uniq -u
```

or:

```
$ comm -23 <(sort 50000-lines.txt) <(sort 20000-words.txt)
```

Comment: This assumes that both files are just lists of words - my reading of the OP's intent was that 50000-lines.txt contains lines with multiple words per line.  But I could be wrong...